# How does ListView Internally Works

Tags: android, listview

I'm little confused about android listview,for data bind, we use Adapters.As far as i know the `getView()`called according to the length of items that we are trying to bind in the listView.So if data length is four then `getView()`will be called for times and it binds data in the listview.Now My question is this,i'm trying to print log in `getView()`so when data bind this log should print but its not happening,on scrolling listview this log is being printed.So i'm confused about this listview.please suggest me.Thanks

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/           http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I know wll how to use listViw ,I have to know only the internal listview working process

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, getView is called as and when required. So views are created only when they need to be displayed.

So that ListViews that have 100s of items will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for replay @nandeesh But can u describe in details

Comment: only views that are shown are created. The views that are not shown, will be created when you try to scroll down to them

Comment: one thing if only two views are created then two times log should print but its not dispaly.